# htaccess https redirect only on specific Zend Frameworks controller/actions

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, ssl, url-rewriting, ssl-certificate

I'm new to this community, but I've found it really useful time to time.

I've searched for the answer a lot, but I didn't find anything like I need. I've tried to solve it on my own, but I still get errors, so I hope to find someone that can show me the right way... :-)

I've got a "classic" ZF website, with many controller/action urls that are redirect to index.php with a .htaccess file.

Now, what I need, is to redirect a couple of controller to https ssl connection excluding some actions of both controllers.

The way I was trying to do it is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 ^!((member|shop)/(?!(index|login))(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^((member|shop)/(?!(index|login))(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|pdf|txt)$ index.php
```

It seems to work when I go to /member controller
But then, when I go to another controller, for example /index or /about it does not redirect to the http connection (port 80), and if I try to change a little the rewrite condition regex it sometimes does a redirect loop and the browser gives me a notice blocking the connection to the site.

Is there anyone that could show me the right synthax to use in my rewrite conditions to allow both the controllers (excluding the given actions) under an https connection and going back to a standard http connection when changing controller?

Thanks in advance.

Alessandro

Comment: Personally I would not touch my htaccess for this. I'd use a redirect in my ZF application if the scheme is not https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved it! I persevered in searching the answer because I think that doing it with .htaccess is cleaner, smarter and easy to maintain.
The problem was essentially due to the regexp used in the "ssl to non-ssl" block that was not correctly matching the value passed (that is best matched now reading the env variable %{THE_REQUEST}, avoiding, in some cases, an erroneus redirects loop.

I paste here the working code for further reference:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1



    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite\.tld [NC]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]



    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /((controller1|controller2)/(?!(action1|action2))(.*))\ HTTP/

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]



    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /((controller1|controller2)/(?!(action1|action2))(.*))\ HTTP/

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]



    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|txt|pdf)$ [OR]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]



    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules instead (replace appropriate lines):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(member|shop)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(member|shop)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

1. These rules a bit simple (HTTPS will be applied to ALL URLs in `/member/` and `/shop/` controllers (e.g. `/member/login`, `/member/dashboard`, `/member/orders/15423/invoice` etc)
2. Negate `!` should be **before** `^` in RewriteCond directive -- if you want your own rules then replace `RewriteCond $1 ^!((member|shop)/(?!(index|login))(.*))` by `RewriteCond $1 !^((member|shop)/(?!(index|login))(.*))`

Comment: First of all, thanks for your suggestion and your time!
I was trying to semplify and implement your solution, but I've noticed a really strange behaviour of this .htaccess.
Now it looks like the following:

Comment: <pre><code>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(member|shop)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(member|shop)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
</code></pre>

Comment: But in this way it always redirects to the index.php file... I also tried to use the ! in front of the ^ but in this way it does nothing, if I put it after it changes to https but it does never go back to http on other controllers...

Comment: @Alessandro Hmm... I do not have HTTPS on my test server so I'm simulating it via subdomains .. and rule works fine. Can you try it in another browser (redirects may have been cached by the browser) or clear browser caches and restart it. You may also try `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`

Comment: Ok I'm going to try it straightforward!
I confirm that with your code (without any changes), on my server, the behaviour is that the /member requests are redirect to http://www.mydomain.tld/index.php, if I call another controller the controller is shown right as http://www.mydomain.tld/othercontroller and if I'm using the https protocol it's redirect correctly to http.
The thing I cannot make working is redirecting to https when I use the /member controller...
And I can't realize why...?

Comment: I've tried on different browsers and computers, but this seems not to be a cache problem: it's as I wrote before, http -> https does not work on required contoller, https -> http works on different controllers, using your .htaccess. Using mine it works on the contrary, it goes to https (only if I put the ! after the ^) but does not return to https when changing controller... strange behaviour, I'm not an .htaccess expert, but this thing is really making me going crazy! :-)

Comment: @Alessandro How big control do you have over your server? Can you edit Apache's config file (`httpd.conf`, `httpd-vhost.conf` or whatever other it may be)? If you can -- then you can turn rewrite debugger ON -- [RewriteLogLevel 9](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) and see exactly what is going on when rewriting occurs -- it is difficult to suggest right thing from overhere if your system is setup differently than mine).

Comment: BTW, the redirect will work if you have trailing slash after controller. I mean -- `example.com/member` will not be redirected but `example.com/member/` will (well -- should). You may also replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` by your domain name (at least for the moment, until it starts working properly).

Comment: Also -- you want only `/member/` and `/shop/` to be served over HTTPS -- all other HTTP only, right? BTH I'm still confused what works with which rule.

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting, so I think it's better to open a ticket to the customer care staff, I suppose.
Thanks for now, I'll try to make it work and if I will, I'll share the solution here.

Comment: Yes, I want only /member and /shop controllers and (possibly) all their relative actions but 3 or 4 on the https protocol.
All other controllers must go on the http protocol.
Now I've used your code (copied and pasted) to avoid using too much customizations (maybe incorrect?) from my part.
This means that with the code you wrote it works right passing from https to http, but it never goes from http to https on the desired controller(s)...

Comment: @Alessandro OK, that's better. 1) create some file (echo.php) and put it into a root folder. Put this inside: `<?php phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);` 2) put these rules right after RewriteBase `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/echo.php` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /echo.php?https=%{HTTPS}&url=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]` `RewriteRule .* - [L]` 3) Type URL that does not work properly and see the results (especially the values of parameters)

Comment: The values seem to be correct, what I cannot understand is why that urls are not redirect to https... maybe the regex is wrong? But it shouldn't, in these tests it's only bout the /member/ controller...

Comment: @Alessandro `^/(member|shop)/` -- it's absolutely valid regex (or you are talking about some other part)? Try hard coding specific URL then: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/member/ [NC]` (type exact URL path there and test if it works). Use 302 code instead of 301 (temporarily, as browsers tend co cache such redirects);

Comment: @Alessandro Use some sort of HTTP monitor (e.g. Firebug for Firefox ("Net" panel) or similar tool for your browser; HttpFox for Firefox is good (it can tell if redirect is fresh or cached etc). Maybe it does work (redirect occurs) but then it redirects back to HTTP? Instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` try `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` (but you said params seems to be OK anyway)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, even if I'm not getting it to work yet...
I forced only one controller/action but this return a browser redirect to the index.php page, I really cannot realize what is going on...

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/member/register [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/member/register [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]`

Comment: @Alessandro My advice (possible the best thing today) - install Apache to your own PC. I assume you are on Windows - if so you can use such bundles like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), enable debugging for rewrite module and see where it may go wrong. Yes, this still may not resolve your issue as you may have a bit diff setup to what you do have on your live server, but it will take you much closer compared to where you are right now - it could be something very simple that we both missing that'll become obvious after debug

Answer (score 0):

A method we use to redirect to https is to leave the default Zend Framework .htaccess settings and create an action helper to redirect to https when required. Our action helper code is:

```
<?php
class RequireSSL extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function direct()
    {
        if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $config['billing']['requireSSL'])
        {
            $redirector = $this->getActionController()->getHelper('Redirector');
            $redirector->goToUrlAndExit('https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you are in a controller action that you need to be accessed via HTTPS you simply call this function at the beginning:

```
$this->_helper->requireSSL();
```

Also, here is another method for using action helpers that is a little more detailed if you need it:

[**http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/110/in-control-of-https-for-action-controllers**](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/110/in-control-of-https-for-action-controllers)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.
Tomorrow I will try it, if no .htaccess success will be achieved!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered where the origin of the problem is, but I'd still need support to understand how to solve it.

I have tested on a local linux machine the htaccess and the result was the same... testing separately the two https condition statements (on and off) they work correctly redirecting basing on the given RewriteCond regex. When putting together only the redirect from http to https works.
Https to http redirect works only if the regex is not matched, else it redirects to http://www.mydomain.tld/index.php

So I finally tried to delete the last htaccess statement and it started to work correctly, but, obviously, it does not find the url, as it does not redirect to the index.php anymore.

It looks like after the correct https redirect the index.php one creates the problem. So I'm asking myself if there is a way to avoid this and make it work correctly.

As I wrote before, this seems to be a common problem of this htaccess, as its behaviour is the same on the test and on the production server (different linux flavours).

I put here the working code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.tld [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 !^((member|shop)/(?!(index|login))(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^((member|shop)/(?!(index|login))(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|pdf|txt)$ index.php
```