# Rewrite http to https and viceversa with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, ssl, https

I want to rewrite all URL to SSL except specific folders/controllers with Zend Framework. For example, I want to exclude auth controller from SSL, then if I access to https://blabla.com/auth I want to be rewrited to http://blabla.com/auth.

I've tried some code in [htaccess https redirect only on specific Zend Frameworks controller/actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580154/htaccess-https-redirect-only-on-specific-zend-frameworks-controller-actions) and [Rewrite all URL to SSL except specific folders with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872859/rewrite-all-url-to-ssl-except-specific-folders-with-zend-framework) but nothing worked for me.

By now this is the code I've in .htaccess file. Any suggestions?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(auth|client)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(auth|client)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

**UPDATE**

It doesn't throw any errors, but when I access to the page with http it redirects me to the index page with https:

```
RewriteEngine On

#If HTTPS is off and this is not /auth or /client - redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 !^(en/x/auth/index) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

#If HTTPS is off and this is /auth or /client - redirect to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 ^(en/x/auth/index) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Does it make sense to NOT use encryption when authenticating?

Comment: Use your apache/virtualhost config file for that.

Comment: Yes Sven, it doesn't make sense, but I was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to change something in the .htacess just create a plugin controller

**Controller plugin**

```
namespace Custom\Controller\Plugin;

class Ssl extends \Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Check the application.ini file for security settings.
     * If the url requires being secured, r ebuild a secure url
     * and redirect.
     *
     * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request
     * @return void
     * @author Travis Boudreaux
     */
    public function preDispatch(\Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $shouldSecureUrl = false;

        $options = new \Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/ssl.ini');
        $options = $options->ssl;

        //if config is empty, exit
        if (!is_object($options))
            return;

         //simpler to use
         $options = $options->toArray();

        if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'production') {

            if ($request->controller == 'ajax')
                return;

            //check configuration file for one of three require_ssl directives
            //secure an entire module with modules.module_name.require_ssl = true
            //secure an entire controller with modules.module_name.controller_name.require_ssl = true
            //secure an action with modules.module_name.controller_name.action_name.require_ssl = true
            if (isset($options['modules'][$request->module][$request->controller]['require_ssl'])
                    && ($options['modules'][$request->module][$request->controller]['require_ssl'])
            ) {
                $shouldSecureUrl = true;
            } elseif (isset($options['modules'][$request->module][$request->controller][$request->action]['require_ssl'])
                    && ($options['modules'][$request->module][$request->controller][$request->action]['require_ssl'])
            ) {
                $shouldSecureUrl = true;
            } elseif (isset($options['modules'][$request->module][$request->controller][$request->action]['require_ssl'])
                    && !($options['modules'][$request->module][$request->controller][$request->action]['require_ssl'])
            ) {
                $shouldSecureUrl = false;
            }

            if (empty($shouldSecureUrl))
                $shouldSecureUrl = false;

            $this->_setupUrls($request, $shouldSecureUrl);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the request to see if it is secure.  If it isn't
     * rebuild a secure url, redirect and exit.
     *
     * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request
     * @param boolean $secure_url
     * @return void
     * @author Travis Boudreaux
     */
    protected function _setupUrls(\Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $secure_url)
    {
        $server = $request->getServer();
        $hostname = $server['HTTP_HOST'];

        if ($request->isSecure()) {
            if (!$secure_url) {
                $url = \Zend_Controller_Request_Http::SCHEME_HTTP;
                $url .= '://' . $hostname . $request->getRequestUri();

                $redirector = \Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
                $redirector->setGoToUrl($url);
                $redirector->redirectAndExit();
            }
        } else {
            if ($secure_url) {
                $url = \Zend_Controller_Request_Http::SCHEME_HTTPS;
                $url .= '://' . $hostname . $request->getRequestUri();

                $redirector = \Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
                $redirector->setGoToUrl($url);
                $redirector->redirectAndExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ssl.ini can be saved in APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs' directory**

```
ssl.modules.default.register.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.default.login.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.default.dashboard.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.default.payment.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.default.password.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.default.profile.require_ssl = true

ssl.modules.admin.login.login.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.admin.dashboard.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.admin.payment.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.admin.password.password.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.admin.password.forgot.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.admin.publicateur.require_ssl = true
ssl.modules.admin.profile.require_ssl = true
```

And finally register the plugin in your bootstrap

```
/* other bootstrap config above */
protected function _initPlugin()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    $front->registerPlugin(new Ssl());
}
```

Comment: Credits goes to Travis Boudreaux.
One more thing you can't get rid of namespacing in controller plugin and rename the class to your suit and correct by the way the registration name in the bootstrap hopes it help

Comment: @sparkling it's zf1 in zf2 you don't register plugin that way and no more bootstrap class! If the namespacing confusing you, you can't get rid of it and give another class name !

Comment: Many thanks Marcel, it works like a charm! I slightly modified the code to enable ssl by default, except controller/actions in ssl.ini file. All other attemps using .htaccess has failed.

Comment: @sparkling You welcome. glad to see it helps. I realized my example was not precise enough in ssl.ini. I will try to find the original blog post, it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you made the conditions wrong. I tried to rewrite:

```
#If HTTPS is off and this is not /auth or /client - redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 !^(auth|client) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#If HTTPS is off and this is /auth or /client - redirect to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 ^(auth|client) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tired it, but I can't get it work... Protocol doesn't change, it's always https

Comment: @sparkling If you have any other rules before these, remove them. Do you try `https://site.com/auth/blah-blah`?

Comment: I have other rules after (not before) these (like in first example) so I need it to redirect all to index.php (I'm working on Zend Framewrok). And yes, I tried https://site.com/auth/blah-blah. It seems request uri condition isn't working as we expected...

Comment: Okay thanks a lot @user5035, now doesn't throw any errors, but when I access to the page (auth controller) with no https access, it redirects me to the main index with https. I edited my current's code in the original answer.

Comment: @sparkling In this case I don't understand, what you want. You wrote in your update 2 steps: 1. If protocol is NOT https and the page is not /en/x/auth/index - redirect to https. 2. Redirect any page to index.php - the last rewrite rule. Remove the last rule, and it won't redirect any page to index.

Comment: Last rule is necessary so all requests need to pass throw index.php, it won't work if I remove the last rule

Comment: user4035 it will maybe work in other contexts, but I think using Zend Framework is impossible. Thanks for your replies